# how to request http page then execute a js function then return the body?

Tags: node.js

i have this code to request a page and return the body

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://www.example.com', (resp) => {
let data = '';
resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
});
resp.on('end', () => {
    console.log(data);
});
});
```

i want to call a function inside the page before i get the body.

for example, there is a button or a link in the page that calls a function to do something, and i want to call the same one before i get the body.

what i'm trying to say, i don't want to write and execute my own code in the page, i just want to use some code that already in the page, as if a normal user just pressed that button.

thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Puppeteer to emulate the browser.

When you send a request using http/s, what you get is just data from the server. The browser is responsible for understand and assembling the html/css/javascript it receives into something which the user can interact with - in your case invoke a specific function based on a user event.

So to invoke that function (and also if that function interacts with the html of the page) you need to construct the DOM using a headless browser like Puppeteer. You might also use PhantomJS but I'd recommend against that.

Just in case, you do not need to do this server side, you can get away with using a browser extension to do your work.

[1] https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/